# Invalid conversion from int to int c++?

Tags: visual-c++

I declared this function :

```
int dice(int roll[8]) {
blah blah
return (score);
```

And called it in int main:

```
newScore = score(roll[8]);
```

I am getting an invalid conversion from int to int error. What am I doing wrong? The error is on the line where I call it.

Comment: 1) `dice` has no closing brackets
2) What's `score`?
3) The "blah blah" section is important because without it, we can't tell you what's wrong with your code.

Comment: In the call, `roll[8]` is a single int, not the array.

Comment: The error points to the fact that you are expecting an array but passing an integer. What you actually want to pass I can't tell - I personally really don't like declaring a function with a "fixed size array" because you may write code that expects this size, then change your mind when you call it. Better keep these things variable - `int dice(int *roll, int n)`

Answer (score 3):

```
int dice(int roll[8]);

int roll[8];
int newScore = dice(roll);
```

This is how arrays are "passed" as arguments.

What happens is dice() receives an int* (which may happen to *not* point to an array of size 8!) and when using roll as an argument, it "decays" into a pointer to its first element.